# Variable with timeout in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout

I need to declare a variable with timeout in Python! Actually I need something like REDIS timeout when we try to read a key after timeout, we get null (None). I know the variable can be deleted and after that, reading the variable would raise errors, but returning None is enough for me. Is there any ready library/package to fulfill this requirement or help me do this without boilerplate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ExpiringDict`. It allows you to define a dictionary with key's expiration.

First, install the package:

```
pip install expiringdict
```

Here is an example for basic usage:

```
import time
from expiringdict import ExpiringDict
vars_with_expiry = ExpiringDict(max_age_seconds=1, max_len=100)
vars_with_expiry["my_var"] = "hello"
print(vars_with_expiry.get("my_var")) # hello
time.sleep(2)
print(vars_with_expiry.get("my_var")) # None
```

`vars_with_expiry` is a dictionary with expiry timeout of 1 second and max length of 100 keys (`ExpiringDict` requires a predefined size param during the initilization).

In the above example you can see how the key `my_var` is deleted and is not available after the `sleep`.

Comment: @timgeb the OP didn't mention that it should be part of the standard library.

Comment: @timgeb I've updated my solution with info regarding the installation of the package. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Your solution is ok for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a custom class for a variable with a timeout, without the need to install a third-party package:

```py
import time


class TimeoutVar:
    """Variable whose values time out."""

    def __init__(self, value, timeout):
        """Store the timeout and value."""
        self._value = value
        self._last_set = time.time()
        self.timeout = timeout

    @property
    def value(self):
        """Get the value if the value hasn't timed out."""
        if time.time() - self._last_set < self.timeout:
            return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value, timeout=None):
        """Set the value while resetting the timer."""
        self._value = value
        self._last_set = time.time()
        if timeout is not None:
            self.timeout = timeout
```

You can save this in a file, say `timeout_var.py`, then import the class in your code. This can be used as follows:

```py
import time
from timeout_var import TimeoutVar

var = TimeoutVar(value=3, timeout=5)
print(var.value)
time.sleep(5)
print(var.value)

var.value = 7
print(var.value)
time.sleep(5)
print(var.value)
```

The output is:

```
3
None
7
None
```

When you assign the `value` attribute a new value, the internal timer is also reset.